# How to correctly cast functions to be newable

Tags: typescript

When I try to make a function `new`-able like this:

```js
01: interface Foo{}
02:
03: var Foo: new() => Foo = function(this: Foo): void {};
```

It will generate errors like this:

> Type '`(this: Foo) => void`' is not assignable to type '`new () => Foo`'.
> Type '`(this: Foo) => void`' provides no match for the signature '`new (): Foo`'.

If I change line #3 to be:

```js
03: var Foo: new() => Foo = function(this: Foo): void {} as new() => Foo;
```

The error will become:

> Conversion of type '`(this: Foo) => void`' to type '`new () => Foo`' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other.
> If this was intentional, convert the expression to '`unknown`' first.

However if I cast it to `Function` first, i.e.

```js
03: var Foo: new() => Foo = function(this: Foo): void {} as Function as new() => Foo;
```

no errors will be emitted. And it also works for casting `Function`/`Date`/`Error`/`String`/etc. `Constructor` beforehand.

So my question is why will casting to `Function` or the `Constructor`s enables one to further cast to `new() => Foo`?

Also, if I want to be precise in the intermediate cast, what should be the definition of the intermediate type?

Comment: @ritaj Well yes, I *shouldn't*, but it's actually [pretty much not allowed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2310#issuecomment-168849651) to do that without [casting it to an intermediate type first](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2299#issuecomment-78393037). And if there's another way to cast to it, I want to know so please post it as an answer :-)